# Reading bytes written by Python with C++ and vice versa

Tags: python, c++

Trying to read in the bytes of a file created with Python. In Python, I can read in the bytes length exactly. And retrieve the data and then successfully perform whatever I want to perform. However, when attempting to do the same in C++, it fails. Not sure of why.

**To write in Python:**

```py
with open("secret.key", 'wb') as secret:
    secret.write(iv)
    secret.write(key)
```

**To read in Python:**

```py
with open("secret.key", 'rb') as file:
    iv = file.read(16)
    key = file.read(eof - len(iv))
```

**Now, to the C++:**

```cpp
std::string key = "secret.key";
std::ifstream ifs(key, std::ios::binary); 
if (!ifs.good())
   throw new std::runtime_error("Screw!!!");
ifs.seekg(0, std::fstream::beg);
char iv[16];
if (ifs.is_open()) {
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&iv), 16);
}
```

There are no errors. It runs fine. But, I am not getting the byte data written by Python. Whereas, when I read the same file with Python it works. But, with C++ it doesn't. What's wrong with my C++ code? How is this done properly?

Comment: "Fails" *how*? What happens when you run the code you show?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it doesn't fail. But, rather, I am not sure I know how to extract the same result from the same position and offset. How is this correctly done in C++?

Comment: Also, `&iv` (in `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&iv)`) is actually wrong. First of all that returns a pointer to the *array*, of type `char (*)[16]` while you want a pointer to the first element of the array. Secondly there's no need to cast as plain `iv` will *decay* to `&iv[0]` which is a pointer to the first element of the array, and will have the type `char*`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes you are correct. So, how can I read the same data with C++ like I am doing with Python above. I tell Python to read the first 16 byte length and its correct and then the rest. How can this be done in C++ properly?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `iv` in the C++ program? And in the Python program that writes the file, what is `iv` there? What is actually written to the file? If you check the contents of the file with a hex-editor, what does it tell you that the 16 first bytes are? Is the contents of the C++ array `iv` the same as those first 16 bytes? How *do* you check what the C++ program reads?

Comment: With Python, it writes and reads same value. While the IV happens to be random every time you run the Python program, it writes it out to the file and reads it back again dynamically.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] of the C++ program. Include how you check the contents of the array `iv` in the C++ program. And please tell us how you compare it to the result written by the Python program? While there are some minor issues, they should not affect the result, and the result should be that the array `iv` contains the first 16 bytes of the file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I need to read the IV into an **SecByteBlock** file for Crypto++.

Comment: Oh I had an idea... Perhaps you think that because `iv` is an array of `char`, it can be written out to the console as a string? Well that's *wrong*. First of all the contents might not be plain characters at all, and secondly it's not *null-terminated*. You need to print the contents of `iv` in a loop, one byte at a time, and converted to an `int` (so you get the numeric value). Also, since it's raw binary data, you should really be using `unsigned char` as the element type.

Comment: Please change `ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&iv), 16);` to `ifs.read(iv, 16);` and then report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reinterpret cast for reading `iv` is not necessary, but `iv` is filled correctly. `seek` is not required either. The variable `key` is used as a file name, but no data is read into it.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("c:\\temp\\test.txt", std::ios::binary); 
    if (!ifs.good())
        throw new std::runtime_error("Screw!!!");

    char iv[16];
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        ifs.read(iv, 16);
    }

    std::string result;
    int c = ifs.get();
    while (c > 0) {
        result += c;
        c = ifs.get();
    }

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```